# Term for a complaint made about somebody present that not everyone knows refers to this person

Tags: single-word-requests

- Person A and B  go to the movies
- Person B drinks very loudly throughout the movie
- Later that night person C comes over to person A and B's home
- In a "joking" manner, Person A says something negative about people that drink loudly to person C, while person B is in the room.
  Person C is unaware that person A was indirectly attacking person B

What is the term for the comment made by person A to person C?

Comment: Somehow I'm thinking of the word 'taunt'. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/taunt

Comment: Its not meant to draw a reaction from person B. More like put down person B indirectly. For all I know there may not be a term or expression. But that's why I am here

Comment: Maybe a 'remark' or a 'rebuke', 'reprimand ', 'reproof ', 'odium', 'reproach'

Comment: Just to clarify @aMammoth you are looking for something to specifically describe a remark which is intended to be understood as a rebuke by another, but which would not appear as such to a person outside of that personal dynamic? perhaps a phrase is more likely than a single word, something like 'coded rebuke' or 'covert rebuke'?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the phrase [snide comment](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/snide) or snide remark.